# sqlalchemy - Performance issues with too many methods/attributes?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have been using sqlalchemy for a few years now in replacement for Django models. I have found it very convenient to have custom methods attached to these models

i.e.

```
class Widget(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'widgets'

     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = Column(Unicode(100))

     def get_slug(self, max_length=50):
         return slugify(self.name)[:max_length]
```

Is there a performance hit when doing things like `session.query(Widget)` if the model has a few dozen complex methods (50-75 lines)? Are these loaded into memory for every row returned and would it be more efficient to move some of these less-used methods into helper functions and import as-necessary?

```
def some_helper_function(widget):
    ':param widget: a instance of Widget()'
    # do something
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not well versed in SA - but typically ORMs use [Lazy Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not have any performance hit when loading the objects from the database using SA using just a `session.query(...)`.
And you definitely should not move any methods out to any helper function for the sake of *performance*, as in doing so you would basically destroy the *object oriented* paradigm of your model.